# "For your sake" vs "For the sake of yourself"

Tags: expressions, synonyms

"For your sake" is found enormously often if compared to  "For the sake of yourself".

[image]

Nevertheless, if we take a look at this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20the%20sake%20of%20yourself%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) we have to come to realize that this second alternative is not a mere linguistic "freak" of the English language and that it has a legitimate existence of its own.

The question is "Should we see no difference in those two forms and consider them as quasi perfect synonyms of one another or rather should we instead acknowledge certain differentiating  nuances attached to one of them? In this latter eventuality what would these nuances be?
A related question : in view of the extremely large difference in the frequencies of use, if synonymity is agreed, what sort of legitimity may we grant to each as an expression of the same idea?

Comment: Perhaps a less opinion-based question might be, not "how should we feel about it," but: "If this usage is so rare, how can we explain these examples in which it's used at all?"

Comment: @AndyBonner My question is not opinion-based. According to what criterion should it be so? There is synonymity ? Well, then that has to be asserted. There is no semantic equivalence ? Then where is the difference?

Comment: "Should we see no difference in..." This phrase is no doubt scaring people into close-voting as opinionated. I'm working on an answer at the moment, at least one to my proposed "how do we explain these anomalies." I think most would agree that where there is such a disparity in use, two phrases can't be regarded as "synonyms" but must justify their contextual uses.

Comment: @AndyBonner I am not inferring there might be any anomaly, on the contrary; the second form, although comparatively rare, seem to me a well established one; I, myself,  do not perceive any difference, but that is not to say there is none, and I think a more informed opinion than mine is necessary, or better, a clear-cut explanation that would put an end to my doubting and possibly to that of others like me. Looking forward to reading your answer.

Comment: One important part of the puzzle: Is "for ___'s sake" always more heavily used than "for the sake of ___"? Or is the distinction especially true for the second person?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it tells us, but the nGram query `for the sake of *,for * 's sake` might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @AndyBonner There is for "argument's sake" and "for the sake of argument" in that lot, the latter being much more common (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+argument%27s+sake%2Cfor+the+sake+of+argument&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20argument%20%27s%20sake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20sake%20of%20argument%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfor%20argument%20's%20sake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20sake%20of%20argument%3B%2Cc0), but that is not so exceptional in view of the non animate nature of "argument".

Comment: Heh, not sure it was worth the wait, but there's my two cents.

Comment: The phrases have a different nuance and the context for the latter is rarer. **"For your sake"** - in your own interests: *"For your own sake, you would be better advised not to shout at the boss."* -- **"For the sake of yourself"** - in respect of one's regard or consideration for something, i.e. one's life, character, reputation, other essential charateristic or possession. *"For the sake of yourself you should stop smoking."*

Answer (score 1):

Of the hits in the Google Books search, most either insert the phrase into a serial construction, use it in opposition to another... or are very old examples, or involve another language. Let's take the first few:

- The [first hit](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Buddhist_Response_to_the_Climate_Emerg/oRwhmqySWNMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22for+the+sake+of+yourself%22&pg=PA129&printsec=frontcover) quotes Sanskrit poetry. It also winds up with some interesting syntax because it makes a point about inverting motivations:

  > There is a Sanskrit verse:
  >
  > > For the sake of the world, you should sacrifice your country.
  > > ...
  > > For the sake of your family, you should sacrifice yourself.
  >
  > It appears the opposite attitude is prevalent nowadays:
  >
  > > For the sake of your country, you should sacrifice the world.
  > > ...
  > > For the sake of yourself, you should sacrifice your family.

  This uses the "For the sake of ___" construction from the outset, though not initially with "yourself," and it makes sense to retain the structure when inverting the logic. Besides translating from another language, it perhaps uses this construction for poetic purposes; using a big old string of apostrophes ("For the world's sake...") doesn't have the same ring.

- [Next hit](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Building_and_Battling/aA7EeNDvTT4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22for+the+sake+of+yourself%22&pg=PA40&printsec=frontcover):

  > I beg you ... for the sake of your own happiness, for the sake of your own soul, for the sake of your own family, for the sake of a loving God, for the sake of a concerned preacher, and for the sake of a concerned church, for the sake of your children who pray for your salvation, for the sake of your husband, for the sake of yourself—I beg you, come now!

  Here again, we have a serial construction, as the preacher strings together a dazzling array of "sakes." And again, he probably chooses the "for the sake of ___" construction for reasons of elevated rhetorical tone, but also because the alternative ("For your own happiness' sake, for your own soul's sake...") becomes a bit of a tongue-twister at times. And although this example seems to date from the middle of the twentieth century, it may well be informed by some of the earlier sermons we'll see to come.
- [The next hit](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Independent/NK3PAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22for+the+sake+of+yourself%22&pg=PA110&printsec=frontcover) is from a 1915 weekly periodical, in what appears to be an advertisement for "the Battle Creek Sanitarium," a health spa. The ad challenges the reader to consider whether they've taken adequate inventory of their personal health, and then makes a familiar appeal to a litany of "sakes":

  > You should know these things. For the sake of your family—for the sake of your business—for the sake of yourself and for the sake of what you are planning this present moment to do tomorrow or next week.

  Here again, the turn-of-the-century tone is already lofty, the apostrophes cumbersome ("your business's sake"?), and the serial construction in full swing.

Skimming over the next few hits, we have a redundant entry for *The Independent*, a 2007 book about planning for retirement, using very similar rhetoric, if in the negative ("If not for the sake of yourself, then for the sake of your family"), another quote of the Sanskrit proverb... we have:

- A 1916 edition of *The New-Church Review*, a Swedenborgian periodical. This one isn't a serial construction:

  > You cannot do good to others without at the same time doing a greater good of some kind to yourself,—although if you do it for the sake of yourself and the reward the return will be of a very low order...

  Here, there is no serial of "sakes," but there is an instance of "yourself" in the previous clause, which prompts the writer to use a mirroring "yourself."
- The *Brick, Tile & Terra Cotta Workers' Journal* gives a proletariat spin to a now-familiar formula: "For the sake of your family, for the sake of yourself, for the sake of your fellow-workers you must organize!"
- [Next up](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Life_Adventures_and_Opinions_of_a_Li/9TpWAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22for+the+sake+of+yourself%22&pg=PA28&printsec=frontcover) we go all the way back to 1841 for *The Life, Adventures, and Opinions of a Liverpool Policeman* ("Part 1," mind you!). Although we get a serial construction again, this appears to be the first time that an actual individual is targeted by the second person, rather than "the reader/listener" in the abstract:

  > I do solemnly trust, for the sake of humanity, for the sake of the commercial character of this great trading country, for the sake of yourself, Mr. Cloothall, that instances of this very unhappy nature are few and far-apart.

So... What are we to conclude? That all instances of "for the sake of yourself" find themselves painted into a corner by parallel construction, and whenever one can, "for your sake" is to be preferred? Well—that's *close* to the truth. Every example so far has mirrored the construction of surrounding phrases.

But ultimately there's one big difference: *For your sake* isn't reflexive, and "for the sake of yourself" is. The outsized reporting of *for your sake* can be explained by all the people willing to do anything for the sake of *another*—"I'd walk through fire for your sake." Limiting the search [to Shakespeare alone](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/) yields 200 or so instances. But "for the sake of yourself" is reflexive; it is not really equivalent to "for your sake," but rather to "for your own sake."

So no, when it comes down to it, context matters a lot (as it always does). I've heard some posit that "there is no such thing as synonyms." Be that as it may, it's certainly true that contextual circumstances help dictate choice of words.